# Find the distribution of $X_{(i)} - X_{(j)}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics, density-function

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim U(0, 1)$ be $n$ random variables
>   distributed uniformally in $(0, 1)$. Let $X_{(k)}$ be the $k$-th
>   ordered statistics, i.e.
>   $$X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} < \dots < X_{(n - 1)} < X_{(n)}$$
>
> How one can find the distribution function for $X_{(i)} - X_{(j)}$
>   (assume that $i > j$), i.e. the probability $\Bbb{P}(X_{(i)} - X_{(j)} < t)$, where $t \in (0, 1)$?

Perhaps, the straightforward approach would be to compute the joint distribution of $X_{(i)}$ and $X_{(j)}$ first. However, it also seems to be not so trivial. I also hope that there may be some trick I'm not aware of to solve the initial problem without computing the joint distribution. It would be absorbing to me to see different approaches to this problem.

I'm also interested in particular case when $j = i + 1$.

Comment: It's easy to show that $X_{(i)}$ is beta distributed with $\alpha=i, \beta=n-i+1$ parameters. You can go on and show that also $X_{(i)} - X_{(j)}$ is beta distributed with $\alpha=i-j, \beta=n-i+j+1$.

Comment: @nicola Could you please provide a reference to this fact or elaborate a little more on this? Would be great to see your comment as a separate answer.

Comment: Say you want to calculate $p(X_{(i)}=t)$. This is proportional to the probability of having $i-1$ variables smaller than $t$ (i.e. $t^{i-1}$) times the probability of having $n-i$ variables bigger than $t$ (i.e. $(1-t)^{n-i}$). See that you get a beta distribution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution The rationale behind is similar to multinomial distribution arguments. For further readings you may try to look for spacings of order statistics, like http://www.nrbook.com/devroye/Devroye_files/chapter_five.pdf